# Subscript out of range for pasting transposed values

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and running into an issue with a paste / value / transpose Macro. I need to be able copy the information from multiple workbooks all with different names, however the workbook where it will be pasted will be the same except for the cells where it will be pasted.

I have tried changing ("Sheet") to the actual sheet name which is "Job Cost Summary" as well as changing "Sheet" to "Sheet1". One thing that happens is when I copy the information from the workbook, it shows the hashed line of the information I have copied but as soon as I hit "macros" the hash marks go away. Not sure if this is important.

```
Sub Pasteinfo()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

I am hoping for a Macro that will allow me to take previously copied information from workbooks & worksheets with different names and paste them as values & transposed into another workbook.

When I run above code I am getting an error 9 that says "Subscript out of range."

Comment: If the worksheet's name is "Job Cost Summary" then you should use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Cost Summary")`  If that doesn't work then either your worksheet name is not that, or it's in a different workbook than `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: What are you copying? When i put some values into Sheet 2 and add this to your code, `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:A10").Copy`, it works as expected.

Comment: @Tim Williams: Thank you! That is what the sheet is named inside the workbook. I will give "ThisWorkbook" a try, thank you.

Comment: @GMalc: Thank you! I am copying information in other excel workbooks with different names and different ranges. It will be different each time. We have different workbooks for each job we have and inside each one of these workbooks we have worksheets for each month. Nothing is "fixed" in that it changes each time I need to copy it and they are pasted to different cells inside "Job Cost Summary" each time.

Comment: If you want to work on the currently-active workbook then you can use `ActiveWorkbook` (vs. `ThisWorkbook` which is is the workbook where your code is running)

Comment: @Tim Williams: Tried switching  `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Job Cost Summary")` to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` and to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ActiveWorkbook")`. All are producing the same result, Subscript out of range. One thing I have noticed is that it is almost like the data I have copied is being dropped off the clipboard as soon as I hit Macros. The reason I say this is after I get the error, or hit the Macros button then hit cancel I can no longer paste the data I had previously copied.

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")` - work*sheets* are contained in work*books*